# Demonstrating a language is regular

Tags: fibonacci, regular-language, finite-automata

So I'm trying to do this sort of problem that says:
Demonstrate that a language conformed by binary numbers of Fibonacci length, is not a regular language.

I really don't know how to approach it nor am I sure if I understand it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: "Binary numbers" of "Fibonacci length". Does this mean strings over the alphabet `{0,1}` whose lengths are Fibonacci numbers (e.g., `1`, `00000`, `111`, etc)? Or does this mean strings over the alphabet `{0,1}` which, when interpreted as numbers in binary representation, are Fibonacci numbers (e.g., `1`, `11`, `000101`, etc)? Either way, you can apply the Pumping Lemma here to prove that they are not regular. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of binary numbers whose lengths are Fibonacci numbers can be shown irregular by either the pumping lemma or the Myhill-Nerode theorem.

For the pumping lemma, take any string `0^p` where `p` is the pumping length. No matter which substring of this you consider, you get a contradiction in fairly short order (for `p > 1`, it is never the case that `p - a`, `p` and `p + a` are all Fibonacci numbers. Proof of that fact is by reference to the definition of Fibonacci numbers.

For the Myhill-Nerode theorem proof, simply show that for any string `x` whose length is the `n`th Fibonacci number, the smallest non-empty strings that can be appended to get more strings in the language have lengths equal to the `(n-1)`th Fibonacci number. Therefore, there are infinitely many distinguishable strings and, therefore, the language is not regular (since a minimal DFA, which has one state per equivalence class under the indistinguishability relation, must have finitely many states).